# Cannot connect kafka connect to schema registry on docker - Unexpected character ('<' (code 60))

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to execute a process to get data from Oracle DB using connect JDBC, but it always fails when is trying to register the schema with schema registry.
This process used to work on older version, but I don't know if was something I changed or if something that changed with API or configurations.
I tried to run some samples using the curl commands on the tutorial from the confluent schema registry with success, submiting a command from connect to schema registry, from https://docs.confluent.io/6.0.1/schema-registry/develop/using.html, except when I use the kafka-avro-console-producer in the example from https://rmoff.net/2016/12/02/kafka-avro-console-producer-error-registering-avro-schema-/-io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.restclientexception/, it's the same error.

My docker-compose is as follows:

```
---
version: '2'
networks:
  stream:
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.0.1
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    networks:
      - stream

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:6.0.1
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
      - "29092:29092"
      - "39092:39092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT,QUICKSTART:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://zookeeper:9092,QUICKSTART://quickstart.cloudera:39092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
    networks:
      - stream

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.0.1
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://schema-registry:8081
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_SCHEMA_COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL: full
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEBUG: 'true'
    networks:
      - stream

  connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:6.0.1
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      # CLASSPATH required due to CC-2422
      CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-6.0.0.jar
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR
    networks:
      - stream
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - |
        echo "Installing connector plugins"
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-xml:0.1.0.18
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt streamthoughts/kafka-connect-file-pulse:1.5.0
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb:1.3.0
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:latest
        # -----------
        # Launch the Kafka Connect worker
        /etc/confluent/docker/run &
        #
        # Don't exit
        sleep infinity
    volumes:
      - $PWD/net.properties:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/conf/net.properties

  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:6.0.1
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
      - ksqldb-server
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CLUSTER: 'connect:8083'
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_URL: "http://ksqldb-server:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_ADVERTISED_URL: "http://quickstart.cloudera:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021
    networks:
      - stream
  ksqldb-server:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:6.0.1
    hostname: ksqldb-server
    container_name: ksqldb-server
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - connect
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:29092"
      KSQL_HOST_NAME: ksqldb-server
      KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
      KSQL_CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING: 0
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      KSQL_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      KSQL_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      KSQL_KSQL_CONNECT_URL: "http://connect:8083"
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'
    networks:
      - stream

  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:6.0.1
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
    networks:
      - stream
```

My connect configuration:

```
name = quickstart-jdbc-source
connector.class = io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max = 1
config.action.reload = restart
errors.retry.timeout = 0
errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
errors.tolerance = none
errors.log.enable = true
errors.log.include.messages = true
connection.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@//#######
connection.user = USER
connection.password = PWD
connection.attempts = 3
connection.backoff.ms = 10000
table.whitelist = DB.TABLENAME
numeric.precision.mapping = false
mode = bulk
timestamp.column.name = DTFIELD
validate.non.null = true
quote.sql.identifiers = ALWAYS
table.types = TABLE
poll.interval.ms = 5000
batch.max.rows = 100
table.poll.interval.ms = 60000
topic.prefix = quickstart-jdbc-
timestamp.delay.interval.ms = 0
db.timezone = UTC
value.converter.schema.registry.url = http://schema-registry:8081
key.converter.schema.registry.url = http://schema-registry:8081
```

Error logged:

```
[2020-12-07 13:26:05,336] INFO Using JDBC dialect Oracle (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask),
[2020-12-07 13:26:05,336] INFO Attempting to open connection #1 to Oracle (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider),
[2020-12-07 13:26:05,562] INFO Started JDBC source task (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask),
[2020-12-07 13:26:05,563] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=quickstart-jdbc-source-0} Source task finished initialization and start (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask),
[2020-12-07 13:26:05,566] INFO Begin using SQL query: SELECT * FROM "DB"."TABLENAME" (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableQuerier),
[2020-12-07 13:26:05,946] ERROR Error encountered in task quickstart-jdbc-source-0. Executing stage 'VALUE_CONVERTER' with class 'io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter', where source record is = /*REMOVED*/,
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to serialize Avro data from topic quickstart-jdbc-TABLENAME :,
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.fromConnectData(AvroConverter.java:91),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.fromConnectData(Converter.java:63),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.lambda$convertTransformedRecord$2(WorkerSourceTask.java:314),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.convertTransformedRecord(WorkerSourceTask.java:314),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:340),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:264),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:235),
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515),
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264),
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128),
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628),
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834),
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema: {"type":"record","name":"TABLENAME","fields":[{"name":"FIELD1","type":"string"},{"name":"FIELD2","type":"string"},{"name":"DTFIELD","type":{"type":"long","connect.version":1,"connect.name":"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}},{"name":"FIELD5","type":{"type":"bytes","scale":0,"precision":64,"connect.version":1,"connect.parameters":{"scale":"0"},"connect.name":"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal","logicalType":"decimal"}},{"name":"FIELD6","type":"string"},{"name":"FIELD7","type":"string"},{"name":"FIELD8","type":"string"},{"name":"FIELD9","type":{"type":"long","connect.version":1,"connect.name":"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}}],"connect.name":"TABLENAME"},
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false'),
 at [Source: (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]; error code: 50005,
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:292),
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:352),
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:495),
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:486),
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:459),
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:214),
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:276),
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:252),
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:75),
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter$Serializer.serialize(AvroConverter.java:143),
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.fromConnectData(AvroConverter.java:84),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.fromConnectData(Converter.java:63),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.lambda$convertTransformedRecord$2(WorkerSourceTask.java:314),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.convertTransformedRecord(WorkerSourceTask.java:314),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:340),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:264),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:235),
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515),
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264),
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128),
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628),
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834),
```

As requested, docker-compose ps output:

```
     Name                    Command                  State                           Ports
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------broker            /etc/confluent/docker/run        Up             0.0.0.0:29092->29092/tcp,
                                                                  0.0.0.0:39092->39092/tcp,
                                                                  0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp,
                                                                  0.0.0.0:9101->9101/tcp
connect           bash -c echo "Installing c ...   Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8083->8083/tcp, 9092/tcp
control-center    /etc/confluent/docker/run        Up             0.0.0.0:9021->9021/tcp
ksqldb-server     /etc/confluent/docker/run        Up             0.0.0.0:8088->8088/tcp
rest-proxy        /etc/confluent/docker/run        Up             0.0.0.0:8082->8082/tcp
schema-registry   /etc/confluent/docker/run        Up             0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp
zookeeper         /etc/confluent/docker/run        Up             0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of `docker-compose ps` please

Comment: Updated with the `docker-compose ps`

Comment: Is this all running on Docker containers, or are you running Kafka Connect locally anywhere? Why's there a mention of Cloudera in the Broker listeners? Also can you update your question with the actual commands you run and the full output that show you testing Schema Registry, and include what host you are running them from (is it the Docker host, or a container)

Comment: No, everything is working on containers. The cloudera reference is because this machine had a docker instance of quickstart docker instance which is not used anymore.
The reference was to allow another machine to connect to brokers using java, testing a service, so I had to create another listener besides the 9092 and 29092.

I used the control center web interface, in the connector I imported the connect file above and executed.